# actionbar with zero margin to the left of the logo

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

I need to remove the left margin of the actionbar to make the logo stick to the left edge of the actionbar. Similar to gmail app. Any idea how? I didn't find a working solution any where.

I`m using appcompat